# Universe of all Types

Tags: type-theory

Suppose we have a universe of all types $U_{\infty}$ that includes itself. Can someone explain why it is unsound -- in particular that we can deduce that every type, including the empty type, is inhabited?

Answer (score 2):

If $U_\infty : U_\infty$ you can run [Girard's Paradox](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Burali-Forti%27s+paradox#GirardParadox). This is a version of [Russell's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) that goes through in type theory (which was originally introduced *precisely* to prevent Russell-type paradoxes from being possible!).
I'll summarize the idea, but there is a detailed account available [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Ecoquand/paradox.ps) ("An Analysis of Girard's Paradox" by Coquand).

You first define a notion of [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), then (using a type of all types) you show that the type of all ordinals $\mathsf{ON}$ is itself an ordinal. Finally, you derive both $\mathsf{ON} < \mathsf{ON}$ (by the definition of ordinal) and $\prod_{\alpha : \mathsf{ON}} \lnot (\alpha < \alpha)$ (by a standard argument) which is a contradiction. The way you use this to show the empty type $0$ is inhabited is by applying $\lnot (\mathsf{ON} < \mathsf{ON})$ (which is defined in type-theory to be a function $\mathsf{ON} < \mathsf{ON} \to 0$) to our (contradictory) proof that $\mathsf{ON} < \mathsf{ON}$. To go the rest of the way, remember there is a function $\text{absurd}_A : 0 \to A$ for each type $A$. So once $0$ is inhabited, all types are.

---

I hope this helps ^_^